# parsing specific words with values from different blocks using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract data as a tuple from a 3GB log file using a Python regular expression.

The format of the log is as follows.

```
2012-11-22 08:57:25,232 [P:DEBUG] moteId=245 statusElem=1
2012-11-22 08:57:25,042 [P:DEBUG] parsed into Tuple_IsSync(isSync=1)
2012-11-22 08:57:26,128 [P:DEBUG] parsed into Tuple_ScheduleRow(row=9, slotOffset=9, type=6, shared=0, channelOffset=0, neighbor_type=0, neighbor_bodyH=0, neighbor_bodyL=0, backoffExponent=1, backoff=0, numRx=0, numTx=0, numTxACK=0, lastUsedAsn_4=0, lastUsedAsn_2_3=0, lastUsedAsn_0_1=0, next=7638)
```

I want the tuple:

```
(2012-11-22, 08:57:25,042, moteId=245, statusElem=1, isSync=1, numRx=0, numTx=0, numTxACK=0,)
```

in a single line.

```
import re
import sys

files=open('/Users/s/Desktop/p.log','r')

match=re.findall(r'\w[\s*moteId\s(statusElem)(isSync)(numTxAck).*]+.\d+',files.read())
f=open('/Users/s/Desktop/w.txt','w')
f.writelines(match)
f.close()
```

My code is not exactly extracting what I am looking for. Any suggestions?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to `.read()` the whole file like that, rather iterate through it line by line.  In fact, why don't you just use grep.

Comment: Read the file line-wise with `for line in file:` and use three different regexp's, each matching one line-type.

Comment: Is there a delimiter that separates those three lines? Or is the file made up of those three lines without separation between them?

Comment: Hello Colt45, the log file (3GB) generated exactly as above. No delimiter that separates those three lines only white spaces among different lines.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this ain't regex, just standard sequence methods and slicing, but it works, at least for the data you presented:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

data = '''
2012-11-22 08:57:25,232 [P:DEBUG] moteId=245 statusElem=1
2012-11-22 08:57:25,042 [P:DEBUG] parsed into Tuple_IsSync(isSync=1)
2012-11-22 08:57:26,128 [P:DEBUG] parsed into Tuple_ScheduleRow(row=9, slotOffset=9, type=6, shared=0, channelOffset=0, neighbor_type=0, neighbor_bodyH=0, neighbor_bodyL=0, backoffExponent=1, backoff=0, numRx=0, numTx=0, numTxACK=0, lastUsedAsn_4=0, lastUsedAsn_2_3=0, lastUsedAsn_0_1=0, next=7638)
'''

flo = StringIO(data)
mlst = []
for line in flo:
    lst = line.split()

    if 'moteId' in line:
        mote, status = lst[3], lst[4]

    elif 'isSync' in line:
        dt, tm = lst[0], lst[1]
        sync = lst[-1][-9:-1]

    elif 'Tuple_ScheduleRow' in line:
        numRx = lst[15].replace(',', '')
        numTx = lst[16].replace(',', '')
        numTxACK = lst[17].replace(',', '')
        t = dt, tm, mote, status, sync, numRx, numTx, numTxACK
        mlst.append(t)
```

I used StringIO to simulate a file, you'll just use the file. And I'm storing the tuple in the master list at the end. But if you do that on a file this size, you may be sorry, depending on your memory situation.  Best to do whatever you need to do with the tuple and then let it be gc'd.  If you have to use regex, then you can still use this logic and apply a different regex for each line type, replacing my slicing, etc.

This is certainly not optimized, but hopefully it will give you some ideas and be of some use.

Mike